# Using single quotes still giving "event not found" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am using single quotes but shell is interpreting it as a history expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z `$1` ] || [ -z `$2` ]
then
  echo `Wrong ID` >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You are using `\`` instead of `'`. Also variables won't expand in single quotes, and history expansion does not occur after variable expansion so you can just use double quotes.

Comment: Are you getting "event not found" when calling this script? If so, that's not related to the script itself but the shell you run it from

Answer (score 2):

You should use double quotes `" "` instead of backticks `` ` ` ``.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]
then
  echo "Wrong ID" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```